# Looping problem with flash audio

Tags: audio, flash, dreamweaver

At my client's request I have placed a song on her website, set to run on loop using flash. The swf is tucked inside of a table in her sidebar navigation. For some reason the swf doubles, then triples, etc. at the end of each play.

I'm using Dreamweaver and Flash and have tried different combinations of parameters: 
Inside Flash: loop on event, loop with stream
Inside DW: loop on and off

Does anyone have a guess as to why/what is causing the swf to stack on itself and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

The parameter for loop needed to be set to false, as the swf itself had a loop built into it.
The correct combination is Event:Loop (within the swf) and loop "false' in DW.